# Syntax for using atomic vectors in tibble list columns

Tags: r, list, vector, tibble

I'm trying to deepen my ability to work with tibbles and one of the things that frequently causes me problems is when I try working with elements within a list column.

More specifically, while this [document](https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/list-columns.html) claims that "Lists can contain anything, so a list column can be made up of atomic vectors, other lists, tibbles, etc.", in my experience the elements within a list column must also be a list.

Here's a MWE

```
tbl <- crossing(a = c(letters[1:5]), b = list(NA)); 
dim(tbl)
# [1] (5,2)
char_vec <- c("a", "b", "cd")

# `char_vec` is an atomic vector, so I expect this to work, but it doesn't
tbl[[1, "b"]] <- char_vec
# Error in `[[<-`:
# ! Assigned data `char_vec` must be compatible with row subscript `1`.
# ✖ 1 row must be assigned.
# ✖ Assigned data has 3 rows.
# ℹ Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
# Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
# ! Can't recycle input of size 3 to size 1.
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred

# This, however, does work
tbl[[1, "b"]] <- list(char_vec)
tbl[[1, "b"]]
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"  "b"  "cd"
```

Can I use an atomic vector as an element in a list column and I am just using the wrong syntax or is impossible and, if so, why?  I thought a list, and thus a list column, could include any type of valid object.

Comment: `tbl$b[[1]] <- char_vec` works as well, and it is not a list. I agree, list-column element replacement can be confusing, this is an example where it seems inconsistent (and I don't have a good explanation).

Comment: I have a visceral negative reaction to seeing `[[` with two arguments. I'm surprised any of those work. When you use a data frame with `[[` as in`df[[ ]]` you are treating the entire data frame as a `list`, which is 1-dimensional.

Comment: @GregorThomas: Sorry to have caused such a reaction ;) However, I'm a little confused, a data.frame is, by definition, a list() which meets particular specifications.  My understanding of the `[[a, b, c]]` syntax is that it pulls the element at position `a`, b`, `c` out of the list/data.frame/tibble context and should return just the value at that location.  I.e. `element <- tbl[[1, 2]]` while `not.element <- tibl[1,2]` will return a 1 x 1 tibble with the element in it.

Comment: @r2evans I tried your suggestion. It evaluates, but the vector is stored as a list.  e.g. ``` tbl$b[[1]] <- char_vec;
 tbl[[1, "b"]]
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"  "b"  "cd"
```

Comment: Apparently `df[[row, column]]` works, but it seems unnatural to me. When I index a data frame with `df[row, column]` I'm treating it like an array, using the standard matrix/array indexing paradigm of single bracket with 1 argument per dimension. When I use `[[` I am treating the data frame like a `list`, which is 1-dimensional, and I expect to only see 1 argument. (Not counting the partial-matching control argument `exact`.)

Comment: But I guess it's there. The `?"[["` documentation page lists both `x[[i, exact = TRUE]]` and `x[[i, j, ..., exact = TRUE]]` under **Usage**, though I don't see any explanation or examples of the `x[[i, j]]` method. It still feels wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to assign an element to a list column, I normally use `[[` twice:

```
tbl[["b"]][[1]] = char_vec
tbl
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   a     b        
#   <chr> <list>   
# 1 a     <chr [3]>
# 2 b     <lgl [1]>
# 3 c     <lgl [1]>
# 4 d     <lgl [1]>
# 5 e     <lgl [1]>
```

Or if I'm assigning multiple elements, I use `[[` and `[`:

```
tbl[["b"]][2:3] = list(1:3, letters)
tbl
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   a     b         
#   <chr> <list>    
# 1 a     <chr [3]> 
# 2 b     <int [3]> 
# 3 c     <chr [26]>
# 4 d     <lgl [1]> 
# 5 e     <lgl [1]>
```

This makes sense to me because `tbl[["b"]]` is the `list`. If I had a `list` `x = list(1, 1:3, "a")` and I wanted to assign the first element, I'd use `x[[1]] = char_vec`. This is the same, except I am using `tbl[["b"]]` in place of `x`.

Comment: Your example and comment helps.  I guess I'm misunderstanding what `tbl[[1, "b"]]` does.  I assumed it referred to an element within a list, but it seems like it refers to a 1-D list with that object.